# DC voltage measured on an AC to AC wall wart - why and how?

Tags: transformer

I have a wall wart that says it is Input 110/230V AC and Output 3.5V AC.

I put voltmeter on it without switching it from DC to AC (forgot to) and measured 8V DC.

I have Googled the subject generally and on this site and found some info saying that it CAN happen but the DC voltage isn't useful as it's not controlled by a regulator - but I cannot find a layman's explanation of *why* it is happening.

Anyone want to clue me in? (This is my first post here.)

Comment: Can you post a photo of the PSU label (and anything else that will help us). What is it's intended function?

Comment: If the wall-wart's inputs and outputs are specified as AC, then it's certainly only a transformer with either a dual or a center-tapped primary.  As concerns the voltmeter, with no schematic for us to refer to, we can't really give you anything but conjecture as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you expect it to say? 0 volts because it should cancel out?

The 3.5V is the 'RMS' (Root of the Mean of Squared voltages) voltage.

Go search for RMS, and think about it.

It is clear that you can't measure an AC voltage (assumed to be a sine wave), by taking the mean over time, as it will sum to zero.

So, we need a way to make all the voltages look positive. Think about that as if you had a bridge rectifier with 'perfect diodes'; the voltage always varies between 0 and its always-positive peak; the diodes never 'drop' or 'lose' any voltage.

Then we'd think, 0 volts to peak is one approach, but it overestimates the 'power' (voltage x current) because it ignores the fact that a lot of the time it isn't close to its peak. It'd be better to have the 'area under the voltage curve', i.e. integrate the values over many cycles. Summing the 'raw' waveform would give 0 as the positive values would cancel the negative.

However, the Mean of the always-positive voltage, averaged over an infinite number of cycles, would be a good measurement, or value to use as it represents the signal value, without worrying about te frequency, or even the actual shape of the signal (function).

So that is what we would like to do. The mathematical operation which 'rectifies' a signal (function) is squaring it; any number Squared is positive.

So the signal voltage (assumed to be a sine wave) is 'rectified' (made all positive) by the S of RMS, which is Square.

Then you calculate the Mean by summing all the Squared (hence positive) voltages, and dividing by the number of voltages that were summed.

Then you need to undo the Squaring, so take the square Root of the Mean, giving the final RMS value.

So that is where the 3.5V AC comes from.

Your voltmeter is measuring the AC waveform somehow. 
AFAIK the result varies between different designs for voltmeters.

A mechanical voltmeter (with a moving pointer) might jitter around, close to zero.

A Digital meter would sample the voltage at discrete points in time. So it might 'hunt' or jump about trying to give a value which never stabilises because it is constantly getting different sample voltages.

Does your meter reading jump aroind? If not it sounds like it might be doing something smarter.

(Sorry for a partial answer my comment got too long)

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: gbulmer - I tried to upvote it, actually - but the interface says I cannot have my votes shown because I'm new. And I can't tell if i did it accidentally or not.  Your reply (and the terms used in it) led me to more info that got me understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this was a digital voltmeter, DMMs take samples of the input, if the sample falls on the same point on the AC wave form each time a measurement is taken, it'll (incorrectly) report a DC value. E.g. if the meter only sampled at the peak of an 8V peak sine wave signal, it'd report that it was seeing 8V DC, it doesn't see what's happening between samples so it's unaware it's looking at an AC waveform. This is a special case of something called "Aliasing" and can result in all kinds of nonsensical results if it's not properly accounted for. If you've got another meter (ideally a different model) see if it gives the same readings (you'll either get zero, a different DC value or a slowly changing value depending on whether the sample rate is a multiple of the AC frequency or not)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure the brick outputs AC3.5V, that means this voltage can only be accurately measured by an AC voltmeter. This voltage will have peak value of 4.9V.

In no circumstances the output should go as high as 8 volt unless the AC 3.5 volt is the voltage specified for certain load attached to the brick. Meaning, the unloaded voltage is normally higher than 3.5 volt.

Hard to answer your question without knowing the full specification of the power brick.